# AsyncDisplayKit Image Display Blinks

Tags: ios, asyncdisplaykit

I'm trying to combine between facebook's AsyncDisplayKit and DMLazyScrollView. When moving to next/previous image, view blinks as seen here:

[image: Display blinks]

Without the AsyncDisplayKit, this problem doesn't occur.

Here's the part of the code that is in charge of getting the image:

```
- (UIViewController *) controllerAtIndex:(NSInteger) index {
    if (index > viewControllerArray.count || index < 0) return nil;
    id res = [viewControllerArray objectAtIndex:index];
    if (res == [NSNull null]) {
        UIViewController *contr = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            ASNetworkImageNode *_mediaNode = [[ASNetworkImageNode alloc] init];
            _mediaNode.backgroundColor = ASDisplayNodeDefaultPlaceholderColor();
            _mediaNode.URL = [NSURL URLWithString:[imagesUrl objectAtIndex:index]];
            _mediaNode.frame = contr.view.bounds;

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [contr.view addSubview:_mediaNode.view];
            });
        });
        [viewControllerArray replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:contr];
        return contr;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Glad to know if anyone has solved this problem.

Comment: By the way, I tried to play around with it, like removing _mediaNode.backgroundColor, or using it without async call, but still it blinks

Comment: Try to set _mediaNode.layerBacked = false. It helps me.

Comment: Nope sorry still not. I the connection of AsyncDisplayKit and this custom uiview doesn't fit well together. It might need more adjustments to work together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we go, here's the answer why it flashes:

> When converting an app to use AsyncDisplayKit, a common mistake is to add nodes directly to an existing view hierarchy. Doing this will virtually guarantee that your nodes will flash as they are rendered.

[async display kit docs](http://asyncdisplaykit.org/docs/getting-started.html)

Comment: I'm using mine in a container, but my ASButtonNode's image still flashing on scroll.